# Hibernate : Transaction Commit time exception (Could not execute JDBC batch Update)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am quite new to Hibernate ,while execution of *tx.commit()* i`m getting the above mentioned exception . I have provided my POJO Class,CFG.XML and
hibernate D A O code,I have used hibernate 3 jars,and using Net Beans IDE(7.3)

Please go through it and let me know where exactly i`m making the mistake .

Thank You

```html
  public String saveEnrollmentData(String uid, String jsonString) {
        String output = null; 
        try {
       factory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("com/integra/HibernateTest/hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(EnrollmentBean.class).buildSessionFactory();
 Session session = factory.openSession(); 
       Transaction tx = null; 
       tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
       
          
          EnrollmentBean enrollment = new EnrollmentBean(); 
          enrollment.setUid(uid);
          enrollment.setJSONDATA(jsonString);
                 session.saveOrUpdate(enrollment);
                
          tx.commit();
                 output="Updated";
                 
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception :"+ex.getMessage());
            output="Exception :"+ex.getMessage();
        }
                 return output;
    }
```

```html
package com.integra.HibernateTest;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="ENROLLMENT_TEST")
public class EnrollmentBean implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column (name="er_id")
private  int id;
@Column (name="uid")
private  String uid;
@Column (name="JSONData",length=1000)
private String JSONDATA;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getJSONDATA() {
        return JSONDATA;
    }

    public void setJSONDATA(String JSONDATA) {
        this.JSONDATA = JSONDATA;
    }

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
             <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property> 
      <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
      
      
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.74:1521:imfast</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">cia</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">cia</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="com.integra.HibernateTest.EnrollmentBean"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Exception :-

```html
9 Jan, 2018 11:37:15 AM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
 at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
 at com.integra.HibernateTest.EnrollmentDAOImpl.saveEnrollmentData(EnrollmentDAOImpl.java:33)
 at com.integra.HibernateTest.EnrollmentServicesImpl.saveEnrollmentData(EnrollmentServicesImpl.java:17)
 at com.integra.HibernateTest.EnrollmentAction.saveEnrollmentData(EnrollmentAction.java:32)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10345)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
 ... 39 more
Exception :Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the COMPLETE stack trace (include all "Caused by" sections).  Format as code, not blockquote.

Comment: I have added the full stack trace

Comment: What does the table definition look like (CREATE TABLE statement)?

Answer (score 1):

The name `uid` is a reserved word according to this page

[Oracle Reserved Words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)

If you cannot change the table definition you *may* be able to use it by quoting it with back ticks, as in

```
@Column (name="`uid`")
```

I'm surprised you were able to create the table with `uid` as a column name.

Comment: Thanks , uid was reserved i changed it now its working

Answer (score -1):

To be more specific for this particular error you can hit the below links to be more clearer.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01747.php

Regards,
Ravindra